# How to convert a decimal number to another system using recursive function?

Tags: python

I am writing a function in Python that takes a number 'n' and a base 'b' that will convert a decimal number to another base using recursive function.

This is what I have so far:

```
def convert_number(n, b):
if n >= 1:
    convert_number(n // b)
print(n % b, end = "")
```

When I test the function with convert_number(15, 3) this is what i get:

> TypeError: convert_number() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Nevertheless, the function works if I use a default value for b.

Since I'm new to programming, I've no idea what that means and what to change.
Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: For a start, the indentation is wrong and currently there is no recursion going on.

Comment: When calling `convert_number`, you need to have to pass two arguments for `n`, `b`. Looks like you only passed in one argument from the error message. It should be something like `convert_number(10, 2)`

Comment: No recursion, no return value, and no function body =)

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback. You should show how you call your function.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to `return` the result of your recursive call, and you need to make sure that you call the function correctly (it expects an `n` and `b` argument).

Generally in a recursive function you first handle the "base case" (the one where the input is small enough to not require recursion), and then you divide the input into one part that you can handle now and one part that needs to be handled by another (recursive) call to the function.

In this function, the base case is `n < b` (i.e. it's a single digit number), and for the recursive case we can use `divmod` to get the next digit and the remainder of the number that needs to be converted.

```
>>> def convert_number(n, b):
...     if n < b:
...         return str(n)
...     n, digit = divmod(n, b)
...     return convert_number(n, b) + str(digit)
...
>>> convert_number(10, 2)
'1010'
```

Comment: You're forgetting cases of b > 10

Comment: Incorrect.  I remembered it and then decided to ignore it.  Figuring out how to handle base-42 numbers isn't really germane to the issue of "how does recursion work".

Comment: Thank you a lot :) Is it also possible to return the number as an integer? An integer probably might be more useful

Comment: An `int` doesn't have the concept of being in a particular "base" -- ints are stored in binary at the hardware level and are converted to decimal by default when you convert them to strings (e.g. when you print them).  Just `return n` if you want the original `int` value.